# date command gives no output

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

I made an alias earlier today that I saved in my .bash_profile. The alias was called date. I had momentarily forgotten that `date` is already a native command on OS X (and Linux) in `/bin`. I removed the alias that I had saved, but now, to use the `date` command, I have to type `/bin/date` instead of just `date`. How can I fix this?

Comment: In Terminal, type `echo $PATH` and post the results.  I am betting `/bin` is not in your path system environment variable

Comment: @Allan here is the result: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Developer/Panda3D/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: It seems `/bin` is in there.  Execute these two commands:  `which date` and `alias`  Either there is a problem with `date` or you have a blank alias set up for `date`

Comment: Got it. date was still set to the alias I had set before. I ran unalias date and it works now. Than you!

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question with the result.  I'll up vote ya...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check your `$PATH` (run `echo $PATH`)
If `/bin` isn't there, then run `export PATH=/bin:$PATH`

After that run `which date` and you should see `/bin/date`

If you still don't have any output, check if `date` isn't alias (run `alias date`)
It should say `bash: alias: date: not found`.

But in your case it may be `alias date='some-command'`
If it is, run `unalias date` and it should fix the problem.

Thanks [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan) for the comments with answer.